# Separate GitHub workflows for Build/Test and Release

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm new to github workflows, so my knowledge is sparse.  I am trying to create a workflow that will run on all branches that does a test build and unit testing of my Go application.  I also have another workflow that will, when the destination is the main branch, create and release executables.  When I push this branch, the first workflow (test.yml) creates a build and runs the unit tests.  I just can't seem to get the second one (deploy.yml) to trigger for the executable release.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

### test.yml

```
# This workflow will build a golang project
# For more information see: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/automating-builds-and-tests/building-and-testing-go

name: Test

on:
  pull_request_target:
    types:
      - opened
      - synchronize
      - reopened
      - ready_for_review
  push:
    branches:
      - main
      - develop
      - "*"
    tags-ignore:
      - "*"

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Install required packages
        run: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y libgl1-mesa-dev xorg-dev

      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up Go
        uses: actions/setup-go@v4
        with:
          go-version: "1.20"

      - name: Build
        run: go build -v ./...

      - name: Test
        run: go test -v ./...
```

### deploy.yml

```
name: Deploy

on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: Test
    # This will eventually be limited to just main
    branches:
      - main
      - develop
      - "*"

    types: completed

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    # `if` required because a workflow run is triggered regardless of
    # the result of the previous workflow (see the documentation page)
    # if: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'success' || github.event_name == 'workflow_dispatch' }}

    steps:
      - name: Install required packages
        run: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y libgl1-mesa-dev xorg-dev

      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        # with:
        #   ref: ${{ github.ref }}

      - name: Set up Go
        uses: actions/setup-go@v4
        with:
          go-version: 1.x

      - name: Build the Go application
        run: go build -o myapp

      - name: Build and release executables
        run: |
          GOOS=darwin GOARCH=amd64 go build -o MastoTool
          GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64 go build -o MastoTool.exe
          GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o mastotool

      - name: Upload executables as artifacts
        if: always() # Upload executables regardless of build success
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: release-artifacts
          path: |
            MastoTool
            MastoTool.exe
            mastotool
```

### UPDATE

It turns out I had two problems.  The first is that Github only runs the workflow defined *on the main branch*.  The changes above were in a feature branch, which explains why I was not getting the results I expected to see.  To resolve this, I added `on: pull_request` to the file on the default branch.  This allows all pull-requested branches to participate.

The second problem was that the multi-step workflow I created was overkill for me.  I simplified into one, like this:

```
# This workflow will build a golang project
# For more information see: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/automating-builds-and-tests/building-and-testing-go

name: Test

on:
  pull_request:
  pull_request_target:
    types:
      - opened
      - synchronize
      - reopened
      - ready_for_review
  push:
    branches:
      - main
      - develop
      - "*"
    tags-ignore:
      - "*"

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Install required packages
        run: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y libgl1-mesa-dev xorg-dev

      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up Go
        uses: actions/setup-go@v4
        with:
          go-version: "1.20"

      - name: Build
        run: go build -v ./...

      - name: Test
        run: go test -v ./...

      - name: Release
        # if: startswith(github.ref,'refs/heads/master')
        # if: startswith(github.ref,'feature/deployment')
        run: |
          GOOS=darwin GOARCH=amd64 go build -o MastoTool
          GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64 go build -o MastoTool.exe
          GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o mastotool
          ls -l

      - name: Upload executables as artifacts
        # if: startswith(github.ref,'refs/heads/master')
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: release-artifacts
          path: |
            MastoTool
            MastoTool.exe
            mastotool
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **repository dispatch event** to trigger deploy.yaml from your test.yaml

**deploy.yaml**

```
name: Deploy

on:
  repository_dispatch:
     types: [trigger_deployment]

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Install required packages
        run: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y libgl1-mesa-dev xorg-dev

      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        # with:
        #   ref: ${{ github.ref }}

      - name: Set up Go
        uses: actions/setup-go@v4
        with:
          go-version: 1.x
```

So, I just have to add another job to call above workflow

**test.yaml**

```
name: Test

on:
  pull_request_target:
    types:
      - opened
      - synchronize
      - reopened
      - ready_for_review
  push:
    branches:
      - main
      - develop
      - "*"
    tags-ignore:
      - "*"

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      jobs:
        job1:
          name: unit test
          // do your stuff
          name: lint test
          // do your stuff
         trigger deploy job using repository dispatch only on master branch
            name: Trigger Deploy job
            runs-on: []
            container: xyz
            if startswith(github.ref, 'refs/heads/master')
            steps:
               - name: Repo dispatch
                 uses: peter-evans/repository-dispatch@v2
                 with:
                    token: PAT
                    repository: 
                    event-type: trigger-deployment
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed suggestion! I found a simpler explanation as detailed in my update above